# How to detect all imges loading finished in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, loading, document-ready

I want to use `ng-repeat` to show more then 100 images in a page. Those images are taking significant time in loading and i don't want to show them getting loaded to the users. So, I only want show them after all of them are loaded in the browser.

Is there a way to detect, if all the images are loaded?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use `load` event like this.

```
image.addEventListener('load', function() {
       /* do stuff */ 
});
```

Angular Directives

**Solution for single image**

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl1">
        <loaded-img src="src"></loaded-img>
        <img ng-src="{{src2}}" />'
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myapp',[]);
myApp
    .controller('MyCtrl1', function ($scope) {
            $scope.src = "http://lorempixel.com/800/200/sports/1/";
            $scope.src2 = "http://lorempixel.com/800/200/sports/2/";
    })
    .directive('loadedImg', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                src: '='
            },
            replace: true,
            template: '<img ng-src="{{src}}" class="none"/>',
            link: function(scope, ele, attr){
                ele.on('load', function(){
                    ele.removeClass('none');
                });           
            }
        };
    });
```

CSS

```
.none{
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jigardafda/rqkor67a/4/

if you see the jsfiddle demo, you will notice `src` image is only showing after  image is fully loaded whereas in case of `src2` you can see image loading.(disable cache to see the difference)

**Solution for multiple images**

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl1">
        <div ng-repeat="imgx in imgpaths" ng-hide="hideall">
            <loaded-img isrc="imgx.path" onloadimg="imgx.callback(imgx)"></loaded-img>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myapp',[]);
myApp
    .controller('MyCtrl1', function ($scope, $q) {

        var imp = 'http://lorempixel.com/800/300/sports/';

        var deferred;
        var dArr = [];
        var imgpaths = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            deferred = $q.defer();
            imgpaths.push({
                path: imp + i,
                callback: deferred.resolve
            });
            dArr.push(deferred.promise);
        }

        $scope.imgpaths = imgpaths;

        $scope.hideall = true;

        $q.all(dArr).then(function(){
            $scope.hideall = false;
            console.log('all loaded')
        });
    })
    .directive('loadedImg', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                isrc: '=',
                onloadimg: '&'
            },
            replace: true,
            template: '<img ng-src="{{isrc}}" class="none"/>',
            link: function(scope, ele, attr){
                ele.on('load', function(){
                    console.log(scope.isrc, 'loaded');
                    ele.removeClass('none');
                    scope.onloadimg();
                });           
            }
        };
    });
```

To detect if all images are loaded,

for each image i generated a `deferred` object and passed its `deferred.resolve` as a image onload callback of the directive and then pushed that `deferred` objects `promise` in an array. and after that i used `$q.all` to detect if all those promise are yet resolved or not.

http://jsfiddle.net/jigardafda/rqkor67a/5/

**UPDATE:** angular way added.

**UPDATE:** added solution for loading multiple images.

Comment: Thanks, two questions about this: [1] does this load event mean finish loading of single image? [2] If so for[1],  How can I detect all load event are triggered?

Comment: you didn't answer..what OP wants..you only thinking about single..what if the images are loaded using ng-repeat

Comment: @Kuan, one way is to keep track of all the images status (loaded or not loaded)  in a service. and once all images are loaded then service will fire some event to notify.

Comment: @pankajparkar and Kuan, I have added solution for loading multiple images, check updated answer.

Comment: @jad-panda appreciated..+1 for your answer

Comment: @jad-panda Thanks, I will try this directive. BTW, could you show me some great tutorial links to learn how t use $q?

Comment: @Kuan see this article its good.  https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2014/02/04/angularjspart-11-promises/

Comment: @jad-panda Hi, Jad, there is another question related to this, which is: for the first time, when I assign a url to a ng-src, the img can trigger the on("load") event, but the second time, if I give it the same url, the load event will not triggered, I wonder how can I still trigger its load event?

Comment: @Kuan, Do you mean you want to change the value of `imgpaths` variable dynamically every time ?

Comment: @jad-panda I post my question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242928/prevent-loading-image-from-cache

Comment: This is brilliant code, thank you @jad-panda for sharing it. I do have a slight issue with it; I'm trying to manipulate some of the images as they are being downloaded (which I manage to do quite easily in the directive load response) but for some reason, I get the 'all loaded' log from the array, somewhere towards all images being downloaded. Not at the very end!

http://148.88.67.145/projects/postcards/images/12.jpg loaded
http://148.88.67.145/projects/postcards/images/10.jpg loaded
all loaded
http://148.88.67.145/projects/postcards/images/10a.jpg loaded

Comment: @jad-panda I can sorted it out with a timeout, but was wondering why this happens. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Check if all images are loaded

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  imagesLoaded: function( callback ) {
    var i, c = true, t = this, l = t.length;
    for ( i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
      if (this[i].tagName === "IMG") {
        c = (c && this[i].complete && this[i].height !== 0);
      }
    }
    if (c) {
      if (typeof callback === "function") { callback(); }
    } else {
      setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery(t).imagesLoaded( callback );
      }, 200);
    }
  }
});
```

- Callback occurs when all images are loaded
- image load errors are ignored (complete will be true)
- Use:

  `$('.wrap img').imagesLoaded(function(){
      alert('all images loaded');
  });`

Note : this code worked for me, Source :

http://wowmotty.blogspot.in/2011/12/all-images-loaded-imagesloaded.html

Comment: OP asked for Angular